# How to add an extra plist property using CMake?

Tags: iphone, macos, plist, cmake

I'm trying to add the item

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key><true/>
```

to my plist that's auto-generated by CMake. For certain keys, it appears there are pre-defined ways to add an item; for example:

```
set(MACOSX_BUNDLE_ICON_FILE ${ICON})
```

But I can't find a way to add an arbitrary property.

I tried using the `MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST` target property as follows: I'd like the resulting plist to be identical to the old one, except with the new property I want, so I just copied the auto-generated plist and set that as my template. But the plist uses some Xcode variables, which also look like `${foo}`, and CMake grumbles about this:

> Syntax error in cmake code when
>   parsing string
>
> ```
>   <string>com.bedaire.${PRODUCT_NAME:identifier}</string>
> ```
>
> syntax error, unexpected cal_SYMBOL,
>   expecting } (47)
>
> Policy CMP0010 is not set: Bad
>   variable reference syntax is an error.
>   Run   "cmake --help-policy CMP0010"
>   for policy details.  Use the
>   cmake_policy   command to set the
>   policy and suppress this warning. This
>   warning is for project developers. 
>   Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

In any case, I'm not even sure that this is the right thing to do. I can't find a good example or any good documentation about this. Ideally, I'd just let CMake generate everything as before, and just add a single extra line. What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked into copying the relevant `*.plist.in` file in `/opt/local/share/cmake-2.8/Modules` (such as `MacOSXBundleInfo.plist.in`), editing it to put `<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key><true/>` (or `@VAR_TO_REPLACE_BY_CMAKE@`), and adding the directory of the edited version in the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`?

If you have CMake installed as an app bundle, then the location of that file is `/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/share/cmake-N.N/Modules`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't notice this answer for a while, but it's great! (I didn't know those `*.plist.in` files even existed. FWIW, I created my own one (based on `MacOSXBundleInfo.plist.in`) and set `MACOSX_BUNDLE_INFO_PLIST` property on my target to that new one.)

Comment: FYI: It looks like `MacOSXBundleInfo.plist.in` has been moved to `/Applications/CMake 2.8-10.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules`... Or maybe there are different install options for CMake that determine where these files end up.

Answer (score -2):

You can add your values using @ and pass @ONLY to configure_file.

Unfortunately there is no simple way to add custom line to generated file.

Comment: What do you mean "add your values using @"; also, I'm not calling `configure_file` anywhere. The plist currently is automatically generated.

Comment: Ah, I thought that this is why you get the error. So where do you get it?